# Own Icon NavBar Bootstrap

Tags: image, icons, navbar

I want to use a picture saved on the server as the PROFIL Icon in the NavBar...

Here's my code... any idea why it's not working?

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="https://mars.iuk.hdm-stuttgart.de/~jv029/profil.php"><img src="/defaultprofil.png" width="15" height="15"> Profil</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://mars.iuk.hdm-stuttgart.de/~jv029/includes/logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the path to the `img src` is incorrect.  Maybe you meant to use

```
img src="/images/defaultprofil.png"
```

The path you used results in 404, while the above goes to this image of a red square: [image: red square]

Comment: Thank you for your reply :)

The path should be right... I also tried this one:
/home/jv029/public_html/images/defaultprofil.png

Comment: Are you saying you don't know the location of the image you want to use?  Your original path was `https://mars.iuk.hdm-stuttgart.de/~jv029/defaultprofil.png` which goes to 404.  As I mentioned, `https://mars.iuk.hdm-stuttgart.de/~jv029/images/defaultprofil.png` actually resolves to an image.

Comment: I uploaded the image into both directories to test if the paths were correct...
I uploaded the image in the same directory where my navbar code is and in the folder images...